# I want to get print dialog box when press print button?

Tags: javascript, printing

I want an to print the receipt of my purchase order. I had already created the button i.e print in my application but i have no idea how can i implement this print dialog box issue.

**here is my fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Ba7arcBC0S

Can any one please help?

Answer (score 1):

The code on your jsfiddle is correct.  You may just need to select jQuery from the select box on the top left (that's currently showing No-Library)

Here it's working in jsbin:  http://jsbin.com/jadiw/1/quiet